# Reducing a Bessel's differential equation to a more 'useable' form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions

Suppose the given equation is:
$$r^2\frac{\text d^2f}{\text{d}r^2}+r\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}r}+(\lambda r^2-m^2)f = 0$$

My text demonstrates the following:

Let $$\text{z = }\sqrt{\lambda }r$$

So that we may have

$$z^2\frac{\text d^2f}{\text{d}z^2}+z\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}z}+(z^2-m^2)f = 0$$

But this looks very strange for

$$z^2\text{$\neq $ }r^2$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are the backslashes part of the usual notation here?

Comment: They're not but for some reason they keep appearing whenever I use mathematica to perform the transmutation to LaTeX.
You can take the backslash to be non-existent.

Comment: What is the textbook you are using?

Comment: @Vlad Richard Haberman
And this equation above was also reiterated by my lecturer but it doesn't make any sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Fourier trigonometric series solution of the heat equation, the general solution for Bessel equation can be written in terms of series of [Bessel functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function).

The final solution will be written as an (infinite) sum over $m$ of Bessel Functions of the first kind and Bessel Functions of the second kind.

---

Now, if you are confused about change of variables, then consider following substitution:
$$
 z : =\sqrt{\lambda}r \implies r = \frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}, \quad \frac{dz}{dr} = \sqrt{\lambda},\\
r \leftrightarrow z   \iff   f(r) \leftrightarrow f(z) \implies\\
\frac{d f}{dr} = \frac{d f}{dz} \frac{d z}{dr} =  \sqrt{\lambda} \, \frac{d f}{dz},  \\ 
\frac{d^2 f}{dr^2} = \frac{d }{dr} \left( \frac{d f}{dr}  \right) =  
\frac{d }{dr} \left(  \sqrt{\lambda} \, \frac{d f}{dz} \right) = 
\frac{d }{dz} \left(  \sqrt{\lambda} \, \frac{d f}{dz} \right) \cdot \frac{d z}{dr} = 
\lambda \frac{d^2 f}{dz^2}
$$
Substituting everything into original equation, we get 
$$
r^2\frac{\text d^2f}{\text{d}r^2}+r\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}r}+\left(\lambda r^2-m^2\right)\,f = 0 \iff
\\
\left( \frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)^2\frac{\text d^2f}{\text{d}r^2}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}r}+\left(\lambda \left( \frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)^2-m^2\right)\,f = 0  \iff
\\
\left( \frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)^2
\lambda \frac{\text d^2f}{\text{d}z^2}+\frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\sqrt{\lambda}\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}z}+\left(\lambda \left( \frac{z}{\sqrt{\lambda}}\right)^2-m^2\right)\,f = 0
\implies 
\\
z^2\frac{\text d^2f}{\text{d}z^2}+z\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}z}+\left( z^2-m^2\right)\,f = 0 .
$$

Comment: Thank you, it now make sense.

Comment: Anyway, I'll like to point out that your use of notation is rather strange. 
Why do you use df/dr(df/dr) instead of d/dr(df/dr)?

Comment: Yes, this is a typo

Comment: Cheers. If yours were legit then I would be very worried that I had blundered my way thru Calculus 1 class.

Comment: No, you are correct =) Thank you for pointing out my mistake, I have edited the post.

Comment: I believe it should also be dz/dr instead of dr/dz.
Since the inversion was done at the outset before the differentiation was done.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected this typo as well